# How can I measure the distance from vector coordinate to a raster pixel?

Tags: coordinates, gis, distance, raster

I have a file of geocoded point data (not pictured) that overlays a 30m cell size raster with the pixels of interest shown in green (image below).

For each point I want to calculate the distance to nearest green pixel. I tried raster to point (an attempt to convert each pixel to a point), but this process takes a long time to complete (days). Are there other viable options for me?

Is there something I can first do to the raster to preprocess it in order to make it a smaller file (dropping pixels if they are not pixels of interest) before attempting the raster to point conversion?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way this can be done is by reducing the number of pixels to the pixels of interest.  For now, I'm using this workflow below. Although it takes some time, it works.

1. Reproject raster and/or point data, if necessary
2. Reclassify the raster (No Data applied to the non-interest pixels)
3. Raster to point
4. Near tool for distance to nearest point